# How do I associate a varbinary column to ".html" in SQL Server 2008 - need to create fulltext index

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, html-parsing, full-text-search, varbinarymax

I need to index a column that stores HTML data and I want to ignore the markup. Here's what I know:

1. Store the column as varbinary(MAX)
2. Set its associated file type to ".html"
3. Enable full-text searching on the column.

This might be a dumb question, but I can't figure out step 2. How do I associate a varbinary(MAX) column as ".html"? I've verified that I have the HTML filter installed.

Comment: It's part of [`CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks... I was looking for a way to do it in Management Studio. That document describes it. Thank you!